# bean not injecting on spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

im learning Spring MVC and i was working on a basic form example, but i dont why a bean its not injecting the information correctly so i would like to know if someone can direct me.

The controller

```
package com.carloscortina.Test;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.carloscortina.toy.model.Member;

@Controller
public final class NomineeController {

private static final Logger log=
        Logger.getLogger(NomineeController.class);

private String thanksViewName ="thanks";

public void setThanksViewName(String thanksViewName) {
    this.thanksViewName = thanksViewName;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Member form() { return new Member();}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processFormData(Member member){
    log.info("Processing nominee: " + member);
    log.info("thanksViewName: " + thanksViewName);
    return thanksViewName;
}
```

the root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<bean id="formAnswer"
    class="com.carloscortina.Test.NomineeController"
    p:thanksViewName="thanks" /> 

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.carloscortina.Test" />
```

im using STS as IDE and the Spring mvc template included.
im not sure the bean its not being injected in the controller so when the form its submitted it redirects correctly, if i hardcode the thanks in the controller it works.

Thanks in advance for the help i know that this might be a basic error , so thank you.

****Edit***
Well, maybe it related to the annotation driven, but I'm still not sure, i havent been able to make this thing work.
So the controller cant rad a bean from the root-context.xml?
or anyone can tell me how to do it with auto wire, the idea its just to not hardcode the value of thanksViewName on the controller.

Comment: Why are you annotating your bean with `@Controller`? It seems you are defining your controller by `component-scan`, so it is not configured in the XML, that's why.

Comment: i would like to say that i understood but, i didn't. im using component-scan with @Controller, so that means that i can't declare a bean in the XML and inject it? 
thankss for the answer.

Comment: What method you use to determine that the bean wasn't injected?

Comment: maybe I'm misusing the term, but i suppose the bean wasn't injected because in the log the variable thanksViewName its null, also the page is not displayed but when i hardcode thanksViewName the value at the log is not null.

Comment: did you include your spring configuration to web.xml? any log from spring?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your servlet-context.xml configuration file, you don't need to declare annotated beans in the XML file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.carloscortina" />
```

My suggestion would be to download Spring Stool Suite (STS) and create a *new spring template project* (selecting the **MVC template**), it will create a runnable project and that way you can see how everything is put together.

Comment: im usig STS and the template, and what im trying to do its separate the view from the logic i mean that the controller doesn't know where the form will redirect after being submitted, and by the example im following the idea its putting the information at the XML but it just didnt work with me.